# Flash AS3 - StartDrag() within StartDrag() on Child MovieClip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip

hey everyone,
my code is listed below.

as you can see, I have a container MC which I have added to the stage. I set its drag constraints using a Rectangle(). I then add the 'cat' child movieclip to the container, and I want this to be dragable too. However, as soon as I click on my cat when testing the MC. It shoots to point x=0 y=0 on the stage and doesn't move.

The container MC can be moved without any trouble.

If I remove the rectangle bounds from the containers startdrag() function. both MC's can be dragged without any issue.

any help would be awesome.

thanks

```
//panning ability
my_x = 800 - myImage.width;
my_y = 480 - myImage.height;

myWidth = 0 - my_x;
myHeight = 0 - my_y;

container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, bgMouseDown);
container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, bgMouseUp);

 function bgMouseDown(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var object = evt.currentTarget;
    object.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(my_x, my_y, myWidth ,myHeight));
}

 function bgMouseUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var object = evt.currentTarget;
    object.stopDrag();
}

//adding ze cat

cat = new ACat();
container.addChild(cat);
cat.x = 100;
cat.y = 400;


cat.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, catMouseDown);
cat.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, catMouseUp);


 function catMouseDown(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var object = evt.currentTarget;
    object.startDrag(false);
}

 function catMouseUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var object = evt.currentTarget;
    object.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: evt.stopPropagation( ) fixed my problem! post this as an answer and I will mark it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `evt.stopPropagation( )` on the first line of the catMouseDown function.

Also try `cat.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, catMouseDown, true);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to test wich is the currentTarget
because the event is fired for the container when you drag the Cat mc

try something like that :

```
function bgMouseDown(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var object = evt.currentTarget;
    if(evt.currentTarget !=container) return;
    object.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(my_x, my_y, myWidth ,myHeight));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your listeners from the container, and make a base class for your dragable objects.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Dragable extends Sprite
    {
        // vars
        private var _rect:Rectangle;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function Dragable()
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, _drag);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _drop);
        }

        /**
         * MOUSE_DOWN
         */
        private function _drag(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(_rect != null) startDrag(false, _rect);
            else startDrag();
        }

        /**
         * MOUSE_UP
         */
        private function _drop(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stopDrag();
        }

        /**
         * Define a boundary Rectangle
         * @param rect The Rectangle to define
         */
        public function set boundaries(rect:Rectangle):void
        {
            _rect = rect;
        }
    }
}
```

There are too many advantages to this to list.